# Updating Rich Text Box from an event handler

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to update the Rich Text Box from the event handler when the message arrive. For some reason the rich text box only updates in the end when all messages have arrived.

Code I am using:

```
    private void OutputMessageToLogWindow(string message)
    {




        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            outputRichTxtBox.AppendText(message);
            test.Text = message;
        }));
    }
```

Comment: tried. same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is that your code is not thread-safe, in case of concurrent messages it is possible that some of the messages will not be updated by executing the following lines at the same time:

```
outputRichTxtBox.AppendText(message);
test.Text = message;
```

So to make it thread-safe, I would recommend to use `lock` inside your `BeingInvoke` method:

```
private static readonly object synchLock = new object();

private void OutputMessageToLogWindow(string message)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        lock(synchLock)
        {
           outputRichTxtBox.AppendText(message);
           test.Text = message;
        }
    }));
}
```